# Definition of the power spectrum

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If $s_1,\ldots,S_{N-1}\in\mathbb R^n$, then the Fourier transform of $$s(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\delta(x-x_i)$$ is given by $$F(f)=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}e^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle f,s_i\rangle}.$$ Now, in eq. (2) in [this paper](https://graphics.cs.umass.edu/pubs/sig12_gns.pdf), there is the following expression for the squared magnitued of $F(f)$ which I don't understand:

[image]

Where does the factor $\frac1N$ come from?

Comment: Hey are you sure that in the first equation you mean $s$ but not $f$?

Comment: @Veliko I'm using the notation of the paper. $F(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $s$ at frequency $f$. A more common notation would be $(\mathcal Fs)(f)$.